# Handling Data conflicts in distributed environment of GridDB

Tags: griddb

In my GridDB deployment I want to test Data consistency, data consistency is of paramount importance. However, I'm concerned about handling data conflicts and maintaining consistency across distributed nodes. I've searched the documentation but haven't found specific details on conflict resolution mechanisms.

My Question is How does GridDB handle data conflicts in a distributed environment, and what strategies or mechanisms can be employed to ensure data consistency and resolution of conflicts in GridDB clusters?

I have provided the code and its showing Error Occured on run. how can I resolve this issue in Griddb. I am just trying to manipulate the existing values to check data consistency.

```
import griddb_python as griddb

# Create a GridStoreFactory instance
factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()

# Define the container name
container_name = "test-container"  

try:
    # Create a GridStore object
    store = factory.get_store(
        host="127.0.0.1",
        port=31999,
        cluster_name="defaultCluster",
        username="admin",
        password="admin"
    )

    # Get the container information
    con_info = store.get_container_info(container_name)

    # Create a Row object
    row = con_info.create_row()
    key = "key1"
    row.set_by_string(key, {"value": "1"})

    # Insert the first row
    store.put(container_name, [row])

    # Create another Row object
    row2 = con_info.create_row()
    row2.set_by_string(key, {"value": "2"})

    # Insert the second row
    store.put(container_name, [row2])

    # Get the row for update
    updated_row = store.get_for_update(container_name, [key])

    if updated_row.has_next():
        row = updated_row.next()
        row.set_by_string(key, {"value": "11"})

        # Update the row
        store.put(container_name, [row])

except griddb.GSException as e:
    print(f"Error occurred: {e}")

finally:
    store.close()
```